# Prevent over booking ticket by using busno and date

Tags: c#, ado.net, database-table

Am working on small project and am new to coding, i want the system to be a booking system whenever specific bus is booked for specific date then that bus will be specific to that date. for example Bus12 is booked to be used on 21 of Aug then if by mistake the admin tries to book the same bus for something else prevent that booking based on checking the date and busno. am simply using web forms, below is my database table and behind code.please help me am not getting any error nothing is stored in my database table when i refresh it.i want if the entered date and Busno is same as the one in table then prevent booking.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;    
    tbDate.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {    
        string check = "SELECT  BusNo, Date FROM Ticket WHERE (BusNo = @busno) AND(Date = @NewDate))";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(check, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@busno", tbBusno.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewDate", DateTime.Parse(tbDate.Text));

        con.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                if (rdr.HasRows)
                {
                    Response.Write("double booking");
                }
                else
                {
                    string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Ticket (BusNo, Date, Time,Bickup,DropOff,Fare) VALUES (@busno ,@date , @time , @bickup , @dropoff ,@fare )";

                    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, con);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@busno", tbBusno.Text);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Parse(tbDate.Text));
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", tbTime.Text);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dropoff", tbDrop.Text);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bickup", tbBickup.Text);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fare", int.Parse(tbfare.Text));

                    con.Open();
                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code is correct, you are also checking duplicate entry condition, You said that it is not inserting data in sql server, just debug `button1_click` event code by each line you will get the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have any kind of exception? This code should fail with a Syntax Error. Date and Time are reserved keywords and cannot be used in a query without enclosing them in square brackets

Comment: how should i do it please. can you please provide a hint.

Comment: _SELECT  BusNo, [Date] FROM_ the same in the insert around the Date and Time field names

Answer (score 1):

Can try removing the `while (rdr.Read())` portion ?

So your code will be

```
using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (rdr.HasRows)
    {
        Response.Write("double booking");
    }
    else
    {
        string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Ticket (BusNo, Date, Time,Bickup,DropOff,Fare) VALUES (@busno ,@date , @time , @bickup , @dropoff ,@fare )";

        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, con);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@busno", tbBusno.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Parse(tbDate.Text));
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", tbTime.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dropoff", tbDrop.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bickup", tbBickup.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fare", int.Parse(tbfare.Text));

        con.Open();
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah i will try to remove the while loop.

Comment: Nothing is working i have removed and still i don't see any data .

Comment: Is there any exception occurred? Any output like "double booking" or something?

Comment: Nothing happen. i don't see anything

Comment: so meaning if you do a debug, running step-by-step, there is no exception? Can you see whether the program goes into the `else` portion ?

Comment: let me check for that.

Comment: you need to perform step by step debugging. if you are using visual studio, you can put the breakpoint by pressing F9 on the line you want to inspect.

Comment: am still not able to figured out this question can anybody help me.when i debug i see nothing happens.

Comment: if you put `Response.Write("insert successful");` below `con.close();`, does it get printed? If not, then something is wrong with your query.

Comment: i can insert but its about my date comparing. i can insert as much as i can but it can be duplicated record i want to prevent it.

Comment: it's quite weird... I see you are parsing the data from your textbox. What do you enter there? And what is the data being inserted to database? Alternatively, you can set unique constraint to your table, with fields of `BusNo` and `Date` as the field. Then you can use `try` and `catch` clause instead.

Comment: I really don't know am trying my best to learn. please excuse my ignorance. i will try whatever you guys advice me thank you so much.

Comment: am able to enter data in the insertion part separately. that's it am new student to all these so may be am messing it so badly. sorry